# How to solve HTTP Error 404.15 Not Found error in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

My ASP.NET MVC application is running on Windows Server 2012 R2, recently the server got a group policy and software update then server restarted. Since then the application gives following error.

> HTTP Error 404.15 Not Found
>
> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long

I followed a few other threads for same issue, when I change `maxQueryString` to 1024 the application url got 1024 bytes of query string.

I even changed the `web.config` file to change the max query string. None of it worked - I'm still getting the same error.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: How long is the actual URL that is being requested?

Comment: @mason it has no query string at all

Comment: It automatically get `ReturnUrl=` part once try access home page

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods:

1. Clear your `returnUrl` Parameter in your Controller Method `[HttpPost] Login();`
2. Add the following to your web.config:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <security>
         <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="1000" />
         </requestFiltering>
       </security>
     </system.webServer>
     <system.web>
       <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>
     </system.web>
   </configuration>
   ```

Comment: I did change the configuration file but still results is same

Comment: Did you try the first method?

Comment: I only have access to publish files, since the application worked without any issues previously, no new code changes made to it also. Could it be something with server environment ?

Comment: Did you make changes to the server environment? The settings in the server that affect the query string are in the web.config above, maybe you can try use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.